# How to implement tree nodes toggling in Vega JS?

Tags: javascript, charts, tree, vega

I'm using [Vega JS](https://vega.github.io/vega) for building a tree chart. In general, my question is the following:

**Vega documentation has a great [example of tree layout](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/tree-layout/). How can I extend it with an ability to collapse & expand its nodes?**

To be more specific, let's consider an example of tree chart that I'm building [here in Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/?#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBMARkoArCGwB2IADQgcSACYqaMsmgGKkDTGwg0AXnDShMATxxn0ylQpAAnOEdNpMThnAC%20io2QySAA2EGgA2qBBCLYYbE4mspghjsQh3mgAZiEQcIpMGg6ooBo4%20mggsHBQANZMbAAeID5%20UUgxFfE0cDLJmOxyigw4KkiYsTBdxkkhAAQA-LMA5JMJ070hS7Ooy6RO-VCbzfJtHegybCpwAOo0KvSp6bbCAAwvrSDRsRdXABJwNDIWEewQyqFEoneJ0%207W%20lzgACE2AwZCowkMRmMJlMZsEFrNwj84P9AVhZgBqWYAFhe8lmRNu9xgFNmAA4XgBdbYEhl3egs150okkoGYFnsjnHU6xTxwOAAFScSBkEEy8QQAAUnGw8I5hqNxhVwqtEhs8YslpYtjslg0lnSTetkublnbuZb7csrjh6J6lrAaMEVC4ZEtJR8vhUDGQyME4CoAHLwkFgmQMYLBRSyCKgOCkXphdAIZG5YZ6zGG87p4LNDk%20DmKA0oVCRGFnECysyKNKg1w5tuxJP7eBICCYRzKEPj1BpjONmgxFUDCoAJXIy8bY2brcj6HlK4aswAamxQR1u080KIAMxvO8R2EVBMH4%20nhjnkA9sEAdlZ7Le9YPu2ACydyzAAgpgwTKgcE5IFOT7xPQcCjuO86LkY2boAAIjQY4JFAaEgE2-a7iA%206HieZ5dp%20l6oP%2097QmRz6UW%20H5frYNJ3u8dZMY%206AJnAADuswAKKaNBqJwQhAlISOY6OOoGHLjheGeDQhGKVupH8eRL5Ue%20NEcdo3FQtKT76WxRl0def73rx5noAiIT9MWLizMB2HST004gKBKgQVBMEaYpC49Jhch7nATgJAYTiWFpyQ6e2FGvtRKacaZQGDpZ6UXr2aCvNxgF8e2CIMJk2TBGwswJgAmt5vQVP5gWSbB6HhSp5HRbF8QJZuSUto5emsXltEFagXGMcNLFpYZGWFVlDkDhUSJjrIHngY1vmCSJ4mxsqDgdUuWHdTFdB9Yl27DalBnsXRkLFaVOWjfN%20VgqIdkActZG-PBmBqk4AUAMLyttT7CWJEmHaFymnfKPUXfFV3JbEt1WQtk1Zc9FmvfdE1FfZ9aKJ4yqquq-ZWDYFT4WMNCZP1IA1HACXnI%20iiTj5ADSLMVJzTUfFTMouDRMT0JcUZ3Izbi2KAARBDW6DhEJfIwA6AKiuGihEgAyiYssgPLKTnPCSIomixyG3Ak501hVW5LohZy4CCtRiLipk4DmrarqLQ-bpcANMoqLxkmVzouN3iFjuulDshqG1lmkWtupMbRVGbAxnGibJiTmexjK%20fZ2HZglcNxB4TQTBxiXEfSAwThQMLcqOKTKpe5T1ixJkgbjE4jiBzg-foAAhAa76UPzYoAD7T7MhRbgAFEsg%20HaH8IQH6XyeuPCCT-BPkAJS1tlFQV0Y1dwAAMhoNR18ijfNzRbfk04CCd9T6CdsEt9hILXcVB7sEPuA8g7DxAAvZIy9V4hxzuHLesId5jAnvXR%20lAvjH0Ag2EAyAnB3w-rEZQDxFCZG1O-YoxFtLoHPlXOMN8ZD4L8BA3o0UkCERoKQLIOQ8gdiVO3CmQ0OwAPQD-BhRCYCOC6D5cwhsXbGxAFIjY-RsxMIgDAJAn9iI0CQGQWQKR-APybgADRkYPcBu9KAWNQU3Sgh5KSL0dLifEvImQEGENyF4mCDENybg1ChZiKgWKsYYuAlBLAsgcTiM0%20IXjcmFBrLAbivEdngmQOAmATH%20LAYE5Be8LHJCcGkzAtjZgAFpZiRLWE4xYLj6BuI8ckgpRS-G5myegIJuTKBNPSWEspFTHHRMWLEnY8TSSYCSc0YmIAehQGTBQ-UWIZH4TYMzGRxl0AAGIoDbMtuImRPc4BBj5mMCRLQWjQiFhUMg2oyza10p2EujhSFsHIaAbITdpzDTFgRCOJFqGV0vrXJ53QjntO0uc2RgQciowzlndeVwJwMDUZ0fQ6ck79jzD5QslQf61HLAaWIFiAxBhDLMAAfLMWJixgBfB2BYr4Pg4nVhPtg6AIQ%20yCLIt8jSEAdaHDjK3YRIAmAw0bC8pAGgZF-Jwekn5wLDlFEjqXRQfC0lLPGDgNA14ABsTD7DqE0GgF4lBRAquRFJVAnhvBTJmXM3MLDh6gBVkyJZcjFafHhIyB4TD4BjNdVC91ozRSWwaFAfZILFVNCYZYMNFCDmgpAAlJhsynAyGiiuVQNAkVrJssmhu0hHVKr5mwDQICIULMrG8wMitQDrJAEJGAdBlWG08Csg2datk7IhZMPY6rtSrIoR2gQAAxYG2rgbDsmUw3B%20DBGXK-oHIiZElKdWzIoUtrD2GcNQPbHhtqEX%20IdTI8YDRPkgHjUUUAU9AlhROnICFQCa1Fs2ayKkf5WRbSYSEF2OaJogDjJkccTCRW5FEe2uiwq2DYBeZbNUvRrgJLPXWi4b8UhMLg5gPW7hB0PSpOWisBsmg4YmlCRNv6wSlOEGc-%20miT1LvuXQAV66HVsP6Nu3dih90Gx8unChdHw0KpkdetmHQH3VvI7EDZ15hAIhk15L9P9AgSYqE3I9wHRyHI0OBv9BhNXoaSAhv1xGwQetQzWfTvQsPaY%20rqphFbCMCdBaAa5yJNXoGdd6xQCB0zTmNQIaNynwR4bORcoVLnbnnrIVKqhMr1JQD-sxvurGOG2A49MmQsyD32pARQojtaHpMI8xIuNEaZHhbc-W1Wls2CVVyNOUpogAsULZQKossqeV8vZfKhNxksy1fSVqvDihfXBua-y2I3L4udaY8KmG4J0PieM5J0S2rh2smHZ%20iFM7o4WCFfxxLm62Ope4ZxjLdr0s5YsIu-1rs7AH16Og2ELIlg2hZFPSgxkFsZkCyADZVJwL-f%205bb9SmlsVAA0B-IGmwM-YQHcFQAqLOYEM6N-Lf6UPIHMyQpIVnAuiGCxiAlMi8vPteE1qtgmKHlYqCN4E06fNGsoAIfzZzlrzsNpYBA9Qax3PbMS4MPRyrQcGOlzL3Gj3NfUZ-NHJmoA0Eboj-w%20sbvyPe-z0lABeLXlKYnci4rBxbMvJMjrHROy2UB83xB%20zgEtam7MEeJ45y9IBqfuaq-T4BKv3UDOdPiUQHimeTMUKzCnTmXc3Iq7TyHOCGfNbdTTqJvuhlM%205KIKd5zdu0eu7z2I6uejA3NURDdSot3HdCHus7WWLu8au6ep3Qn7u%20Tz-er7T660NqbcDxTkUjcqZ4-3dToGtOw-h4r89BnEM-Yx2h7Hlnldg-BFRrMyg5dWC98cqclBm%20zC1xrnXQzU9B5APZx3JXKfOYjxUIrltvOe7jwGhPVTBmzH9zsPzR%20Q-ntK1Ty-6Ao839j2dgfz-0TzmGTwEEP2oywR8CAA).

If you click on the nodes, they will toggle (expand or collapse), allowing you to see particular branches of the tree. This feature works fine unless you try to collapse the top-level node (region) while keeping the second-level nodes (districts) expanded. In that case the tree will look like this:

[image: broken tree screenshot]

It happens because of the way I handle this interaction:

1. When you click on a node, `toggledNode` signal is triggered, which in turn triggers `toggle` action in the `expandedNodes` data array. I.e. by clicking on a node, I add or remove that node to the `expandedNodes` array (more precisely, we add/remove a reduced object with only `name` property)
2. Thus `expandedNodes` data contains information about which nodes are **explicitly expanded**. But it doesn't know if those expanded nodes are inside of a collapsed parent node.
3. Then, to find out which nodes are actually visible, I use `visibleNodes` data. There I apply `filter` transform with the following expression: `!datum.parent || indata('expandedNodes', 'name', datum.parent)`. I.e. I check only one level up: if the node's parent is present in the `expandedNodes` array , I consider the node as visible.

The problem is the following: *I can't find any way of extending this functionality across multiple levels.*

Probably I could write some hooks to check the same condition across 2 or 3 levels, e.g:

```
!datum.parent ||
  indata('expandedNodes', 'name', datum.parent) && 
  indata('expandedNodes', 'name', datum.myCustomFieldWithParentNode.parent) && 
  indata('expandedNodes', 'name', datum.myCustomFieldWithParentNode.myCustomFieldWithParentNode.parent)
```

But it seems too complex for such a simple problem, and also it's not a final solution. In theory, a tree may contain dozens of nesting levels: what to do then?

I found one useful expression in Vega: [treeAncestors](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#treeAncestors). I could easily write a solution in JavaScript, where I have loops and array methods such as `.some()` and `.every()`. But apparently Vega doesn't support any expressions to iterate over an array. So even though I can get an array of tree node ancestors with `treeAncestors` function, I can't do anything with it to verify that all ancestors are expanded.

Either my approach is wrong, and somebody can find a better algorithm for doing the same, which doesn't require iterating over arrays (except for `data` and `indata` expressions) - or it's a current limitation of Vega.

Comment: Can this be marked as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example I created for expanding and collapsing tree nodes (also supports pan and zoom).

There is a dataset named treeClickStorePerm which stores the state of the nodes which have been opened on the canvas. This is populated by an intermediate dataset named treeClickStoreTemp which in turn are driven by various signals defined at the top of the spec.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATONABONHJnaT0ALTZtkTADZwpAAiht9+pHiQG4xzIrh2mAT2MARJMRqzjAISQoKBpUYyxcfCIAdxjKfRpxAGs4WQTKMwQCBIJZLyZA4IJpECifejRQCBoycSR9NBAARgAWAAZWkABfGXhqrAqQKpq6hoBOdq6ZfKhEskU2BnFZBoBiADMBDY3ipAZMNiqALzgGnCRlmTPZVPEyNAEZIdr9CDQAbVBahBP0cTZ5ADqZRgxWIdQYP0a426nyQ3waf3kAAk4H1MKDwT9mgIYSAvj8QKRFGooHUAHL-OAAcSsGP0ELQjVauPxDRgbGUhwkmHJlJpODpDNQLWZUlh8PQEB5xISZHccFUIJkYPpkJkEneoDgpHEmFeqFAmBcOAJam+imK9Hm2EMaFFIAYOFymAJAFpGl0ALosuEExEnZWYu3qjQfEDauC6-WG40EqDxGbFZCKRKs36UyYOp1IF0NZ0MBCsZa4iNRgZGk0NM1wC0yK1sG2Q+2O50Ejqdb1ivG+hGUpF9eJkfqB1UNN6tT3FDWoMOlvXl2MNBALCBwNhEpNIFNpvEZ7pZ1unekzAAUDicAEFxFAFPtFBATwByc9wADCdSgEEfJnzhZ8AEoTEfHxH3-SYtR1ecDRACsCWXBhVwWdF9xbHMCXHScOx9CUQBoCAAFEAA8ziWFJBR+VoQ01cNIOjGDF3QeMaETGRk1THt03kTNUNzdBf3SGAaH0WRHHEYwAD5jFaYwADIZOMBJnSQJ8X1fBNEgAZTvOAAAUawQb9jGA2RDP42AhJEyMAElZAgDD-wAfgcCFUDWOpVy9bCCUIxQkFuAMDzQsdKOMUpZHoTCux3FxfP84oePQkLeiHTBIvFAlZDYKJJBHIVxAYCwqJnCDIygmCFlgSMLkC3i8QK+oS1opcVxSLLxBMfYGFgKUt3RGQEoaQiXBPMCsKijiQEIqAGFrQkg1QfLCpAadZya9B4NXTLso6iqYB64kdq6+Alni7NaogBM4BPQjMoQUbO3ShoXGm2aVTy+qitW0r9RADbWu2+xdv2zBDsqk7+rOgkLuYq6XFu+6vLzOB9B5cj3koidPpKstisGBZFBvBpSiWLLLQY36WuXUhijMcQIALH5nKMEAmDgTAoicUMY0rdaWq2yRcTEGbCfQYmtrJnmKYQuBHU8rtYKrXaqYC2n6YlJmZDWISXQtdA50oTrKogOJIzIehjAAXit4wPQ7CHDz4trjAc4w3n5jDXUIkafzat5Gk9V1hv-T1jFCccpAnOXHvQPzYA5NGZwxz0sZo76ifgZHTodkA3gSIlMCfQjoDqOBDK9-9AIU8R86fFxi8MQyg+D8DU5x7nTSB6U+pALWUZrBp9cN+BjcMW56Cti2ACZuMhsdrtujDjAAamMG7dD9z1-2MAhjEnkwTzh9eJ2X4xD4QDet53yfMIe7scMIuBCO7gb0HDsKIpb6LH+f2fX8o5KsBpTvgSLkugE6NBTnOH6UQM76AAITFDWByEWGsaoEhwFlE8jRKDtAgcYfW8gUZIAAJrGAAFTGAwVELBAA2EwBDkY8gALKUgri3KBAwngjD4nhTA099xIIJozRQEJ7ZBR4VKRo29jCpClPw2+O5ZGYA9LlCikC1rt0VkdYGiDtb9z1pBA2u0FAmzHjACe-CxG1RwAkWA7heGxyunOUaXYOHQS4fUCRfCZ7ZyUfIxGXjp6qODMtLmrcoKaPQEPZWNMJBq2EaInuejdbhKMUdExo8zbmKtpYtBpxbEwHsT1a8TjIII3GvfW6WdxGDEutdb+YF1Fp3cdUZ4SMiE+JqW8KaM1F4rwgCRa6L0t4UMITyReO934wBMD0xQG8T4DL8kMmaIyZGMKQBM0KwIgFuMqK07hIBQEIE6bVN4sd2RzOPiveeR8Q6umMOcjk9lyHGCOSYR5lyQ7XLXuff2xh7kfOeRQo5Oy1pyAMExFieS-5SCmTfAJIAz7VPOnUlwDSpxhN2YMfZni5DrJOehZ6vSrnGEWeIA+wyXljI2X8neACQanxevM-pgyiWKFWdS+ZdLUQpVBc0vZwxcVHIJWOQFfzrln0XgC68FyL4vLeQ8mVTzxXGAPgvP50q45zP9qskF7CwWyAhepZFiUpD0vhRUqGpJDCyApICYEJqGgnn9ECcKMAd5kpuXdf8ZCpmfwmvXFIdq4AojRI6mOTAHz+lDSlD1rL4Y+vpf6nCgbZAADFuSNAAMzhpAFgrNcalk-Irr6h1CLU0Zt1I0IJ0K83VsLeS4tPq-XlutSkStyiVG1qwY0BtXqS0tstQ0VNABpHSVkY3Dm7QIPtTbS1uuTVakusgAAyNAEB0FzSeSerRZ0JvneUO2cgcwoFxjuIWQj4qKFxeEPAhACC+SiNQOgjAmDSwJtyUq6RdAEB0n4KyrpPDeFkAQeU4g4BMFdBpdkURSSrgIMgbIAB5RQFBxB4RzOoAApDugAKo4OAOHWivhgL1HIJ6RBiAFkO0WPg4C4bYLhuo9RHj4xFnjYWAUHB+QgII45uMFboD4wVFAMhH44BScAZILhQj8UMKQfQECziiUwKERa+gTAmnvBIVA-EtNUZMIkGxumcwFkoEZmgnQdg-UUy3QTPcOQIBE8UcTknpOydM4WeTyNGgr0fAAH0fEvOTEZ9B72U6VDzmAzPecU5pmsVGTPRcLPpiQhnjP8Qs1ZmQSAbOWMiQ5xQTnLAueIm5uAMmQsKakX5wLwXPMmwU5PWrQWqvIyzVICLuoosxdC75oydW2thfi9p8QSWzOpfasYCz43CxZesw0fQObcT2eEyVsTZWGhSYq7NxrPmT4Bdaw12LzWBtHeS3tpbLWV5DeaJ1rckWZHHb6wdwbz2mvXaGx1yhCWdN6d+1NmbmWbHZZALlxbzQ7PkzW6J8Mm30Dbcq+9-bn3kdhdRxd2LWbrtPcx6F5oOOhsPC66p3HvXquvfO+T5Gp3Dv1bxwp7HZ2bto7uz90bu3JvpZCMDyzC30D6AEFDyWSDhK6ORrZd4IBbMyDC8UJb8vIey6F7fezEm2DCDgFAbuWsJf6jeCAaTaNVfQ8c85jbEm8wNbenAczFX+e4WLPLU3RXzdw8t+gRwRJVwngGfEAu-Ebd25cFIQ7FcMIO7UJgW0K2XfFdh65q3F2g8k4d6n2PIvkmlY98ei7UfDDGDgRbIy6nHyyXkvxfPdgi9GUWPILW4GTLC4JEgMgcw+C5hkHMBYOBXBS58MUVPdY6C2mCSbkXZv1vu5SYHzElBJtp4B83hoMPs8z+t3PizDut9jWjjBAj759CfmKBe9jYV6OMeY5aWKvHHPUXs1KXyag1guGKEb9AA-LgPd1CO+36B0-O6SwvhJhszsjLAtKCoNDPg+AuCPiZirjKaYbTgCptJCbuQnD7jg4ziIrFCETFDyCKg0yCTCSiQgC3xYEgBD70QT6u5T6J58QNbp4KITSqTEGWQ5QcaXpRIH4fivB1g358b37kyt7t4UCd4gDd6Oh97YGp7JxJJ65S6yHqh4BS426vByFYEG7mQkGRhIZMCa7a7qEZ4Eir4W4pI4DHiJAnhmRsGiR6EGF6ih4gSNJg4-TaHsE2SvC77AJVgEZXg3hSgch8GcHsaqS8HX48aCECZx5u4UEvj+G3hBFr6+GXglKBH3gqQ8FH5fg-gNY+BATzANigTL5CaWDYCRji7CT6776pEBF3hGGAEmGT4J7w655mbxFpH1Hz7f7dwUHMY6Q9FeHME4SsEWSiQXgWAn5samh+GdFJH8GRF37RGSzq4OGVGS7YH9GDHFCf4+Ff4qa4HFCv4yAEHlAyDuGkHj4t5t6OBiEBS65VGKE9GD7PEyAD5yFsAqHYFqGxKLDdwbqSByGSG96v6bEWADEqbqE5bVHMYkZjG6H6Fa7zg5YWBwk6HiCvgLC6g7HLBXEr7NHJH-6WHWENawm2EIkOEQBOEmQuF9GonkniCeFRw+HcFOBqTMSaTaS4aIACisacYpFwAJHpHBHcZ0xRFhirZZ5mHDpdyyjyiKhF7ugOT8SnEwDGAAA8xewMcpCo9AC0lIheFs0kckheeEREJE8gsgLsemPRlsxe-oamBpRexp8kZpxEfklp1ppJ4JgxdpxgDpbkLwGBjRpw8waxmsNACh2BuxrI+xpUhxMgxxeKhB5xDJZBxhDQIhtxQUEZUZBu7xyh1RAJZBXe8wUhoJ+Z1UsZlBrxk0Rx+BupSoIAFxFR3owxMxbJ6kWkHIuk+k5E+uHxYSDg1QZA+igwsptw8p9A4kRpOxdMNY6IDBPImRnZHJ3Zjg3JCAOAxRK2ygbeY5-oc5q4xIDQcCbpFpKQXpy5z4B+XZXJPJoErk6Bdme5o5KSh5MgjgMSH+BE7ppEVpSkK5b4d5PZm525-4T5QZzJO4L4K6SALgSEUx-JtG8gDGTGkxCxYpSxEp0OUp0+DQikJ6QF7JMw65vZRWhkxkpkeRsgLiBWj+mGL+b+f+juLxKmv+oJNZBxGZrJAU3w9A-wnCOKUBagsgsBmY-oGkNAxw1EHivYyIPKWAS8+czEvI8g-ILcclnEcArq9AS8Fy0l3Ial1ItIR6CBW4SBGgKBBygZHkmB1RSZeBJxjZRB8JgJPFhW8ehJbRhYLgS8J49KBAk8tJP0r+Hlph+Fkobahcga34-EhEIVg0qaLcFBVBq2BJ0pS5E2zx3hO4aw9U+GTgcFCFewSFXBNRcAxViFmFt+RWQhks+gOgiQssms8w-GFVaJ7BzFnFVBDxGxlZJZc0qo1RLZ4g9hSJwRo1TJeJAuTVLVPcbVApnV4xGFhuLFWxkJ6x1RBZQ1EIMJ9JblTJKJ+gy1FJE16ZIZs1bAzVvJC1YCvFh+x+Mg7+rFuZjx0ZuJqiI1aZM1nlbu9BIAXuCWV0FhXUVhHRdRQRxFvB1FF2AEQEzh-4G8keBGEJ8ZuVE03gVQtgwawRp+JhBVBGVVpVNV4pBWvcOs3lhF15qkIFjgekFFCNJkuRcNtF0FE0yAhEulMAV4sgk63c+NDQWNNAONlIIpAh2FBWWZHeAUwJ0hBuqpg1fV1RitMgTlOBHxXxWhWJ-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-tb14BFVaN2JtDchbEv91B6COYTZCQOsgQag1MkFq4rV91oA4TAuEd6d4Y14GY0EL8oA2dII0EfVpwGT8BDg11OlDqEBSDikj8bAawzqfYA4aIq9b9qGG9AEkkSpu8lAAgqArQlAkO+4j+bTnCbaDQYj+MJ+wlnuEY94INxJENiRGRd9b4MNwz69H98NRkiNyNtDtDNGu4XEzlSgKgag04IAuG8AlCtpH5aTDQwJNM8QAo+TzMawi10EJThIkTot8g5TkYZgXE1Tv8oAeBDTkZYuMDJ+qzMDDD+4fqnTBygjlI3NmYz0AwjT6ASZDDFLOLPQili5fDw6batqfYdLmYvcniDL60NYo5AVF0vui96zM0r9L4CTmAFcJgwA+gszlAowzQnQndSzyQFDuK5oPLe0+g-LJcT4grigwrqNPR4rxgkr0rGjow8rmYZgig4GigAASucDQAhAMDbmgJPPuC9GILrJyz5QJG5eJK0A5I+BglkzWI+KgI+HAfuPsOYGoEC16xffuCk9RDuIJEOIOFOjC1AMoKoOoGyIMylKqquIgBAMYPEMkA8sYAAGp8DGBvpkAPLFv0B4QyJsCRhfiYChQciJDGASD2CfPAn4KGDfC6guH2aODa5znZPa40B5OgNiaVMIugA1N1n4u4p0CICUBsTUBlk4Cj22yJnKsNDtgRmTErsEWkSES9P9PIh5tYCaY9Gf0TONAuyqtXTquauGDavmD4yGQk4Gz6sqaGvGtzOGOusQVHvjnzBKunsf7nuXvRo3sMq-vjP-JPvGAvu8sat906s-v3sisGuVxAeUCmvyuzOZhJrQe4QuiFibvAmUBJq4sdNetrvUdbiJBbs96UAtq3P3NjpWQ1uBCzBlngx4rPPZtvO8f8czCSHCejtIkTs1g5PTs-CzvNmAtoCoJwtVOLtIvLtMdUcbusfseOi7sksHsf76c0fbt0d0uuijrjr81kessUd2cTqssMcLoUcnjMcGcphGc7tTKd3ssrMYOMRfsSOPBbNcVfp4fcXKGBB0CgmgDOvSuuvcd768cNmievMaAgAZd1jkxjvdzBu+RTszu4OqcqDqciLMyacLvQrItmeUfruWcceER7s4EUfectfGf0q2dMu8cOf7jkdesueDcyB4sjeL30Mr2-sWaBdCQcuDBYvG3iOzRaVRe6h-tOCivxseUuhPzycle5PKflc7jVm1e8P1e6dENINYK7qkqDJzqDoddesng0J7q6ADplqazcgAhOdJfzQgA0ITD7j5Crip2XfJflQCgCILfBe2iherebPEO-sxfo11jfyNe-sL4CLchSUyXOdMsdrZqZjxAbr0s3cEtMtCPAh9fLprrk9svchOuA+H4i3KC7cZ37dFe6gKelcncsMskwQj4BQXcDBLsouvdMgffeoHogj7iJeU+4rbqTwy9fcLqYGDiENQ+GBrDIRTC5bIwJCQ+A-7Aw-HuLfrePhqPuDNB+DqMRsY8HcUeo8i9M+6j4+XfrcVqZrtdk+bqE-Lo09up082oM+bq4-YnQRQ9s9MAc+3N7eY9vG89HdKfMMFNC-+imBplzvwuXcS+NddeGe0dTL-KqqjBq-NrfcvdK8EUWfF9WeBW5J1CtIs+jie5hqg+G8Q9t9Ci-Q+CyAx4W-w9xhhdreReo--vo8wSY8u-3ujV+sOS-ujVhuO8OYe-SVe+Rc+9Vq5JIJR8A-t8gCx-x+3NtmdBAA/view)

[image]

```
{
    "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
    "description": "Zoomable, collapsable tree by David Bacci: https://www.linkedin.com/in/davbacci/",
    "width": {"signal": "1400"},
    "height": {"signal": "1000"},
    "background": "#f5f5f5",
    "autosize": "pad",
    "padding": 5,
    "signals": [
      {"name": "nodeWidth", "value": 190},
      {"name": "nodeHeight", "value": 45},
      {
        "name": "startingDepth",
        "value": 1,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "timer",
              "throttle": 0
            },
            "update": "-1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "node",
        "value": 0,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "click",
              "markname": "node"
            },
            "update": "datum.id"
          },
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "timer",
              "throttle": 10
            },
            "update": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "nodeHighlight",
        "value": "[0]",
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "mouseover",
              "markname": "node"
            },
            "update": "pluck(treeAncestors('treeCalcs', datum.id), 'id')"
          },
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "mouseout"
            },
            "update": "[0]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "isExpanded",
        "value": 0,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {
              "type": "click",
              "markname": "node"
            },
            "update": "datum.children > 0 && indata('treeClickStorePerm', 'id', datum.childrenIds[0])?true:false"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "xrange",
        "update": "[0, width]"
      },
      {
        "name": "yrange",
        "update": "[0, height]"
      },
      {
        "name": "down",
        "value": null,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": "mousedown",
            "update": "xy()"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "xcur",
        "value": null,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": "mousedown",
            "update": "slice(xdom)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ycur",
        "value": null,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": "mousedown",
            "update": "slice(ydom)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "delta",
        "value": [0, 0],
        "on": [
          {
            "events": [
              {
                "source": "window",
                "type": "mousemove",
                "consume": true,
                "between": [
                  {"type": "mousedown"},
                  {
                    "source": "window",
                    "type": "mouseup"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ],
            "update": "down ? [down[0]-x(), down[1]-y()] : [0,0]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "anchor",
        "value": [0, 0],
        "on": [
          {
            "events": "wheel",
            "update": "[invert('xscale', x()), invert('yscale', y())]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "xext",
        "update": "[0,width]"
      },
      {
        "name": "yext",
        "update": "[0,height]"
      },
      {
        "name": "zoom",
        "value": 1,
        "on": [
          {
            "events": "wheel!",
            "force": true,
            "update": "pow(1.001, event.deltaY * pow(16, event.deltaMode))"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "xdom",
        "update": "slice(xext)",
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {"signal": "delta"},
            "update": "[xcur[0] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width, xcur[1] + span(xcur) * delta[0] / width]"
          },
          {
            "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
            "update": "[anchor[0] + (xdom[0] - anchor[0]) * zoom, anchor[0] + (xdom[1] - anchor[0]) * zoom]"
          },
          {
            "events": "dblclick",
            "update": "[0,width]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "ydom",
        "update": "slice(yext)",
        "on": [
          {
            "events": {"signal": "delta"},
            "update": "[ycur[0] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height, ycur[1] + span(ycur) * delta[1] / height]"
          },
          {
            "events": {"signal": "zoom"},
            "update": "[anchor[1] + (ydom[0] - anchor[1]) * zoom, anchor[1] + (ydom[1] - anchor[1]) * zoom]"
          },
          {
            "events": "dblclick",
            "update": "[0,height]"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledNodeWidth",
        "update": "(nodeWidth/ span(xdom))*width"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledNodeHeight",
        "update": "abs(nodeHeight/ span(ydom))*height"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledFont13",
        "update": "(13/ span(xdom))*width"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledFont12",
        "update": "(12/ span(xdom))*width"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledFont11",
        "update": "(11/ span(xdom))*width"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledKPIHeight",
        "update": "(5/ span(xdom))*width"
      },
      {
        "name": "scaledLimit",
        "update": "(20/ span(xdom))*width"
      }
    ],
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "source",
        "url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase/main/Organisation%20Tree%20Chart/data.json"
      },
      {
        "name": "wideToTall",
        "source": "source",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "{key: datum.level1,parent: null, person:datum.person, kpi:datum.kpi}",
            "as": "l1"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "{key: datum.level1+ '|'+datum.level2,parent: datum.level1, person:datum.person, kpi:datum.kpi}",
            "as": "l2"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "{key:datum.level1 + '|'+datum.level2+ '|'+datum.level3,parent: datum.level1+ '|'+datum.level2, person:datum.person, kpi:datum.kpi}",
            "as": "l3"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "{key:datum.level1 + '|'+datum.level2+ '|'+datum.level3+ '|'+ datum.level4,parent: datum.level1 + '|'+datum.level2+ '|'+datum.level3, person:datum.person, kpi:datum.kpi}",
            "as": "l4"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "{key:datum.level1 + '|'+datum.level2+ '|'+datum.level3+ '|'+ datum.level4+ '|'+ datum.level5,parent: datum.level1 + '|'+datum.level2+ '|'+datum.level3+ '|'+ datum.level4, person:datum.person, kpi:datum.kpi}",
            "as": "l5"
          },
          {
            "type": "fold",
            "fields": [
              "l1",
              "l2",
              "l3",
              "l4",
              "l5"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "project",
            "fields": ["key", "value"]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.value.key",
            "as": "id"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "reverse(split(datum.value.key,'|'))[0]",
            "as": "title"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.value.parent",
            "as": "parent"
          },
          {
            "type": "filter",
            "expr": "datum.title != 'null' && datum.title != 'undefined'"
          },
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "groupby": [
              "id",
              "parent",
              "title",
              "value"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.value.person",
            "as": "person"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.value.kpi",
            "as": "kpi"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeCalcs",
        "source": "wideToTall",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "stratify",
            "key": "id",
            "parentKey": "parent"
          },
          {
            "type": "tree",
            "method": {
              "signal": "'tidy'"
            },
            "separation": {
              "signal": "false"
            },
            "as": [
              "y",
              "x",
              "depth",
              "children"
            ]
          },
          {
            "as": "parent",
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.parent"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeChildren",
        "source": "treeCalcs",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "groupby": ["parent"],
            "fields": ["parent"],
            "ops": ["values"],
            "as": ["childrenObjects"]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "pluck(datum.childrenObjects,'id')",
            "as": "childrenIds"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeAncestors",
        "source": "treeCalcs",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "as": "treeAncestors",
            "expr": "treeAncestors('treeCalcs', datum.id, 'root')"
          },
          {
            "type": "flatten",
            "fields": ["treeAncestors"]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.treeAncestors.parent",
            "as": "allParents"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeChildrenAll",
        "source": "treeAncestors",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "project",
            "fields": [
              "allParents",
              "id",
              "name",
              "parent",
              "x",
              "y",
              "depth",
              "children"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "fields": [
              "parent",
              "parent",
              "id"
            ],
            "ops": [
              "values",
              "count",
              "min"
            ],
            "groupby": ["allParents"],
            "as": [
              "allChildrenObjects",
              "allChildrenCount",
              "id"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "pluck(datum.allChildrenObjects,'id')",
            "as": "allChildrenIds"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeClickStoreTemp",
        "source": "treeAncestors",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "filter",
            "expr": "startingDepth!=-1?datum.depth <= startingDepth:node !=0 && !isExpanded? datum.parent == node: node !=0 && isExpanded? datum.allParents == node:false"
          },
          {
            "type": "project",
            "fields": [
              "id",
              "name",
              "parent",
              "x",
              "y",
              "depth",
              "children"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "fields": ["id"],
            "ops": ["min"],
            "groupby": [
              "id",
              "name",
              "parent",
              "x",
              "y",
              "depth",
              "children"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeClickStorePerm",
        "values": [],
        "on": [
          {
            "trigger": "startingDepth>=0",
            "insert": "data('treeClickStoreTemp')"
          },
          {
            "trigger": "node",
            "insert": "!isExpanded? data('treeClickStoreTemp'):false"
          },
          {
            "trigger": "node",
            "remove": "isExpanded?data('treeClickStoreTemp'):false"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "treeLayout",
        "source": "wideToTall",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "filter",
            "expr": "indata('treeClickStorePerm', 'id', datum.id)"
          },
          {
            "type": "stratify",
            "key": "id",
            "parentKey": "parent"
          },
          {
            "type": "tree",
            "method": {
              "signal": "'tidy'"
            },
            "nodeSize": [
              {"signal": "nodeHeight+10"},
              {"signal": "nodeWidth+140"}
            ],
            "separation": {
              "signal": "false"
            },
            "as": [
              "y",
              "x",
              "depth",
              "children"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.y+(height/2)",
            "as": "y"
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "scale('xscale',datum.x)",
            "as": "xscaled"
          },
          {
            "as": "parent",
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "datum.parent"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "fullTreeLayout",
        "source": "treeLayout",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "lookup",
            "from": "treeChildren",
            "key": "parent",
            "fields": ["id"],
            "values": [
              "childrenObjects",
              "childrenIds"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "lookup",
            "from": "treeChildrenAll",
            "key": "allParents",
            "fields": ["id"],
            "values": [
              "allChildrenIds",
              "allChildrenObjects"
            ]
          },
          {
            "type": "lookup",
            "from": "treeCalcs",
            "key": "id",
            "fields": ["id"],
            "values": ["children"]
          },
          {
            "type": "formula",
            "expr": "reverse(pluck(treeAncestors('treeCalcs', datum.id), 'id'))[1]",
            "as": "treeParent"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "visibleNodes",
        "source": "fullTreeLayout",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "filter",
            "expr": "indata('treeClickStorePerm', 'id', datum.id)"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "maxWidthAndHeight",
        "source": "visibleNodes",
        "transform": [
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "groupby": ["depth"],
            "fields": ["depth", "x", "y"],
            "ops": [
              "count",
              "max",
              "max"
            ],
            "as": ["count", "x", "y"]
          },
          {
            "type": "aggregate",
            "fields": [
              "depth",
              "count",
              "x",
              "y"
            ],
            "ops": [
              "max",
              "max",
              "max",
              "max"
            ],
            "as": [
              "maxDepth",
              "maxNodes",
              "maxX",
              "maxY"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "links",
        "source": "treeLayout",
        "transform": [
          {"type": "treelinks"},
          {
            "type": "linkpath",
            "orient": "horizontal",
            "shape": "diagonal",
            "sourceY": {
              "expr": "scale('yscale', datum.source.y)"
            },
            "sourceX": {
              "expr": "scale('xscale', datum.source.x+nodeWidth)"
            },
            "targetY": {
              "expr": "scale('yscale', datum.target.y)"
            },
            "targetX": {
              "expr": "scale('xscale', datum.target.x)"
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "filter",
            "expr": " indata('treeClickStorePerm', 'id', datum.target.id)"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "scales": [
      {
        "name": "xscale",
        "zero": false,
        "domain": {"signal": "xdom"},
        "range": {"signal": "xrange"}
      },
      {
        "name": "yscale",
        "zero": false,
        "domain": {"signal": "ydom"},
        "range": {"signal": "yrange"}
      },
      {
        "name": "kpiscale",
        "zero": false,
        "domain": [0, 100],
        "range": {
          "signal": "[0,scaledNodeWidth]"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "colour",
        "type": "ordinal",
        "range": [
          "#6f6f6f",
          "#4472C4",
          "#3A8E50",
          "#ED7D31",
          "#a63939",
          "#6338a6",
          "#3843a6",
          "#38a695"
        ],
        "domain": {
          "data": "visibleNodes",
          "field": "treeParent"
        }
      }
    ],
    "marks": [
      {
        "type": "path",
        "interactive": false,
        "from": {"data": "links"},
        "encode": {
          "update": {
            "path": {"field": "path"},
            "strokeWidth": {
              "signal": "indexof(nodeHighlight, datum.target.id)> -1? 2.5:0.4"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "scale": "colour",
              "signal": "reverse(pluck(treeAncestors('treeCalcs', datum.target.id), 'id'))[1]"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "node",
        "description": "The parent node",
        "type": "group",
        "clip": false,
        "from": {"data": "visibleNodes"},
        "encode": {
          "update": {
            "x": {
              "field": "x",
              "scale": "xscale"
            },
            "width": {
              "signal": "scaledNodeWidth"
            },
            "yc": {
              "field": "y",
              "scale": "yscale"
            },
            "height": {
              "signal": "scaledNodeHeight"
            },
            "fill": {
              "signal": "merge(hsl(scale('colour', datum.treeParent)), {l:0.94})"
            },
            "stroke": {
              "signal": "merge(hsl(scale('colour', datum.treeParent)), {l:0.79})"
            },
            "cornerRadius": {"value": 2},
            "cursor": {
              "signal": "datum.children>0?'pointer':''"
            },
            "tooltip": {"signal": ""}
          }
        },
        "marks": [
          {
            "name": "highlight",
            "description": "highlight (seems like a Vega bug as this doens't work on the group element)",
            "type": "rect",
            "interactive": false,
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.x1"
                },
                "y": {"signal": "0"},
                "fill": {
                  "signal": "indexof(nodeHighlight, parent.id)> -1? merge(hsl(scale('colour', parent.treeParent)), {l:0.82}):0"
                },
                "height": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.height"
                },
                "width": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.width"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "KPI background",
            "description": "KPI background",
            "type": "rect",
            "interactive": false,
            "clip": true,
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.x1"
                },
                "y": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.height-scaledKPIHeight"
                },
                "height": {
                  "signal": "scaledKPIHeight"
                },
                "width": {
                  "signal": "(item.mark.group.width)"
                },
                "fill": {
                  "scale": "colour",
                  "signal": "parent.treeParent"
                },
                "opacity": {"value": 0.2}
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "KPI",
            "description": "KPI",
            "type": "rect",
            "interactive": false,
            "clip": true,
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.x1"
                },
                "y": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.height-scaledKPIHeight"
                },
                "height": {
                  "signal": "scaledKPIHeight"
                },
                "width": {
                  "signal": "scale('kpiscale',parent.kpi)"
                },
                "fill": {
                  "scale": "colour",
                  "signal": "parent.treeParent"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "interactive": false,
            "name": "name",
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "(10/ span(xdom))*width"
                },
                "y": {
                  "signal": "(6/ span(xdom))*width"
                },
                "fontWeight": {
                  "value": "600"
                },
                "baseline": {
                  "value": "top"
                },
                "fill": {
                  "scale": "colour",
                  "signal": "parent.treeParent"
                },
                "text": {
                  "signal": "parent.person"
                },
                "fontSize": {
                  "signal": "scaledFont13"
                },
                "limit": {
                  "signal": "scaledNodeWidth-scaledLimit"
                },
                "font": {
                  "value": "Calibri"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "interactive": false,
            "name": "title",
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "(10/ span(xdom))*width"
                },
                "y": {
                  "signal": "(22/ span(xdom))*width"
                },
                "align": {
                  "value": "left"
                },
                "baseline": {
                  "value": "top"
                },
                "fill": {
                  "signal": "'#4D4B44'"
                },
                "text": {
                  "signal": "parent.title"
                },
                "fontSize": {
                  "signal": "scaledFont11"
                },
                "limit": {
                  "signal": "scaledNodeWidth-scaledLimit"
                },
                "font": {
                  "value": "Calibri"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "interactive": false,
            "name": "node children",
            "encode": {
              "update": {
                "x": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.width - (9/ span(xdom))*width"
                },
                "y": {
                  "signal": "item.mark.group.height/2"
                },
                "align": {
                  "value": "right"
                },
                "baseline": {
                  "value": "middle"
                },
                "fill": {
                  "scale": "colour",
                  "signal": "parent.treeParent"
                },
                "text": {
                  "signal": "parent.children>0?parent.children:''"
                },
                "fontSize": {
                  "signal": "scaledFont12"
                },
                "font": {
                  "value": "Calibri"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, the chart looks amazing!
Could you please provide more explanation behind your solution? In particular, please point us to where it solves the core problem in the question so that I can accept it as the correct answer and close the topic.

Comment: I'll add a comment now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use treeAncestors and then use a flatten transform to get a dataset that you can query. In your case it would look something like:

```
{
  "transform": [
    {
      "as": "treeAncestors",
      "type": "formula",
      "expr": "treeAncestors('tree', datum.id, 'root')"
    }
  ],
  "name": "tree-ancestors",
  "source": "tree"
},
{
  "transform": [{"fields": ["treeAncestors"], "type": "flatten"}],
  "name": "tree-ancestors-flatt",
  "source": "tree-ancestors"
},
{
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "filter",
      "expr": "indata('selected', 'value', datum.treeAncestors.id)"
    }
  ],
  "name": "filtered",
  "source": "tree-ancestors-flatt"
},
{
  "transform": [{"type": "aggregate", "groupby": ["id"]}],
  "name": "filtered-aggregate",
  "source": "filtered"
},
{
  "transform": [
    {
      "type": "filter",
      "expr": "indata('filtered-aggregate', 'id', datum.id) "
    }
  ],
  "name": "filtered-tree",
  "source": "tree"
}
```

Comment: It is at first, but that's where the flatten transform comes into play. It takes the initial row and gives you a new row for each field in the array, so that you can just access it easily.

Comment: sorry, I've deleted my comment right before you answered it. I got it now, `treeAncestors` is turned into an object after the `flatten` transform.

Comment: So I tried your implementation on my chart, but it doesn't work as expected. Of course, I replaced `id` fields with `name`, and made some other renamings to adapt it for my sample. Here is the link: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/329742ab6fbc3104cb3bfb911fbc4fcb/spec.json. It does hide the lowest nodes when I collapse the root node, but as you can see, when root node is expanded, the lowest nodes are always visible. I.e. it doesn't respect the middle nodes' state. I don't fully understand what's going on with all these `filter` and `aggregate` transforms, could you suggest please?

Answer (score 1):

Vega doesn't seem to have a recursive way of solving the problem for your question" hey, if all my parents are expanded, then I am visible as a node ".

You can check indeed conditions for all levels you wish to define.

```
{
      "type": "filter",
      "expr": "!datum.parent || indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.parent)&&datum.depth==1||(indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.firstParent)&&indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.secondParent)&&datum.depth==2)||(indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.firstParent)&&indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.secondParent)&&indata('expandedNodes','name',datum.thirdParent)&&datum.depth==3)"
}
```

The code above says to VEGA : " hey check if all of my **defined** parents are expanded and filter me if any of my parents exist **but** are not expanded

To see the full solution with your case, please check :
[spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/2249fedd4c603c4670d1838b4c795ab2/spec.json)