# Simple way in Vega to colapse and exspand a Tree node

Tags: tree, vega

Following the Vega documentation example of tree layout I have basic tree structure with 3 levels. The data is ingested from ES and the model caters for 4000 child nodes and 63 middle tear nodes.  [image]

In order to have a manageable view I would like to collapse child nodes  to the middle tear and allow the user to expand or collapse a middle tear node at a time

I have tried adapting tie solution posted here [How to implement tree nodes toggling in Vega JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69302893/how-to-implement-tree-nodes-toggling-in-vega-js) but my knowledge is to limited to get the functionality i need.

Could someone help with a simplified  solution  based on this sample?
[simple tree](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how to "collapse child nodes to the middle tear and allow the user to expand or collapse a middle tear node at a time". This solution only adds a Vega signal to handle mouse event and a filter to the tree dataset.

[image: Vega tree interactive]

[View in Vega online Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-LzZqtNUZhYjVfoCpVGA6cIohqFmRIcaskCzkD6UpQ6oyHImWTSkAMqNDyw0EyORSlAwcH-IEilBCEHxheEAB5kVRAAfOCdAACmBMDITgaE4URZE7R0AAyPDMTQ-s7iwpECR3VZ1k2bZdjCKlKgASkLLcOXmKJYnGIYvGyTluV5OUSzLAJK1ZUAh34jZohicYtyHDiYi6R8QACDJ9QwVT5wkYoTFKCAYCQY0gUSCRV3pRkFjyMxLzZNj0CgV4AjlPN0A4uB7FKEsyEBUAuEQTlkDIZB1TkNhkGiNBQGZKcR1Kb8NltOQMOqSMQEXZU0G5IULOQRQZKrFydWUyxlVEqKihZEAFNkmQ9Qc+RIpAP4AUapSYEa+KXz7Ip2tS2tlRbRqBRMIV5gAYigSa6VpGbP0Kx5nleOLSsa6L0EkkK6voxqE0yRrhkXIbBUBU4Gj67k2EG1BQGG0b0DGyxHummRmscRq72ukBOsSu9UrbUBvvmJtUu-ExdM+6B8k5ByTCcmRAaBZLepmuTCscfQ1XhlbPrW4cBNSraGs+3bgPEgwAwBjIuvWvMQe0gBlBcfJAW7AQATlSpgLyk8RmdZ+YEEqWQzGepqcGBZmPsphL5jvC5HvWANTr+jqqcSm8rEsRW0HCZWUYZIA)

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "An example of Cartesian layouts for a node-link diagram of hierarchical data.",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 600,
  "padding": 5,
  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "signal_selected_node_id",
      "init": 1,
      "on": [
        {
          "events": "symbol:mouseup",
          "update": "datum['depth'] == 1 ? datum['id']: signal_selected_node_id"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "tree",
      "values": [
        {"id": 0, "parent": "", "type": "root"},
        {"id": 1, "parent": 0, "type": "H-VC"},
        {"id": 2, "parent": 0, "type": "H-VC"},
        {"id": 3, "parent": 1, "type": "L-VC"},
        {"id": 4, "parent": 2, "type": "L-VC"},
        {"id": 5, "parent": 1, "type": "L-VC"}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {"type": "stratify", "key": "id", "parentKey": "parent"},
        {
          "type": "tree",
          "method": "tidy",
          "size": [{"signal": "height"}, {"signal": "width - 100"}],
          "as": ["y", "x", "depth", "children"]
        },
        {
          "type": "filter",
          "expr": "datum['depth'] <= 1 || (datum['depth'] == 2 && datum['parent'] == signal_selected_node_id)"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "links",
      "source": "tree",
      "transform": [
        {"type": "treelinks"},
        {"type": "linkpath", "orient": "horizontal", "shape": "diagonal"}
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": {"scheme": "magma"},
      "domain": {"data": "tree", "field": "depth"},
      "zero": true
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "from": {"data": "links"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {"path": {"field": "path"}, "stroke": {"value": "#ccc"}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "symbol",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {"size": {"value": 100}, "stroke": {"value": "#fff"}},
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x"},
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "depth"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "tree"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "text": {"field": "type"},
          "fontSize": {"value": 9},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"field": "x", "offset": 10},
          "y": {"field": "y", "offset": -10}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```